# Apply patch in liferay

Tags: liferay-6

I have liferay 5.2.3. I am in to the process of migrating from 5.2.3 to 6.2. The portal says we need to migrate to major release for example, 5.2.3 to 6.0 to 6.1 and finally to 6.2.

I have successfully migrated from 5.2.3 to 6.0. When migrating to 6.1, while oracle db upgrading I got the following error.

```
    12:23:40,589 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][MainServlet:217] com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24005: Inappropriate utilities used to perform DDL on AQ table SYSMAN.AQ$_MGMT_LOADER_QTABLE_G

com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: com.liferay.portal.verify.VerifyException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24005: Inappropriate utilities used to perform DDL on AQ table SYSMAN.AQ$_MGMT_LOADER_QTABLE_G

    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.java:1306)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
```

When I was searching for a solution I got a patch [here](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/16698661?_19_delta=20&_19_keywords=&_19_advancedSearch=false&_19_andOperator=true&_19_resetCur=false&cur=2)

Now I am confused how to apply patch in liferay? Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

How does the patch look like? the link you provided is not a direct link to the patch. I just wanted to have a look at the files in the patch. I once had to apply a patch from here https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-2340. I had an ext-environment which had similar file names as those in the patch. I made changes to the corresponding files in the ext-env and it worked perfectly fine. I was also told it was the correct way to do that if you have an ext environment.

Comment: The issue is LPS-29479. So you have any idea what might be the patch for this. The issue is like oracle compatibility for liferay.

Comment: Well I don't have much idea on this as I am using older version of liferay and never encountered this. But i think you can try making changes as per this link (looks like the patch you want to apply) -> 
https://github.com/brianchandotcom/liferay-portal/compare/317feb2d20...affdf86096

or you already tried this?

Comment: This happened while I am migrating the liferay from version 6.0 to 6.1. So portals will be same. The issue is with few liferay tables of oracle nature.

Comment: If you want to apply the patch try making those changes as per the above link and test.HTH.